# window.onbeforeunload not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.onbeforeunload not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802007/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-in-chrome)

window.onbeforeunload=function(); is not working in chrome.. It works for IE and Mozila but it not works for chrome.. Is there any another way to use window.onbeforeunload=function(); in chrome......... Thanks in advance.......

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload` works fine in Chrome.  Please show us your code.

Comment: You need to provide a more complete example if this question is to be distinguished from the possible dup.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested the following in Chrome and it works...

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        alert("Hello");
    };
```

Comment: Tested in Chrome 16.0 and it does not work.

Comment: @LapinLove404 - good spot I just tested it in the latest version and got the same result.

Comment: Actually, I have been looking into this and... it seems that Chrome will only allow one thing with onbeforeunload : setting the text to display in the browser confirm message.

Comment: We can't do anything other than that?

Comment: do you want to make us fool, it is not working any version on chrome