# check if window is open on pageload (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I would like to detect on page load if the `targetwindow` is open. the `targetwindow` gets opened from the main window. However if i refresh the main window the connection to the `targetwindow` gets lost.

when i click the button in the mainpage the `targetwindow` is opened, i then check every second if the `targetwindow` is open or closed and do stuff that i load from `localStorage`

```
function checkWindow(){

var windowObjRef = window.open('_external', 'targetWindow',
`toolbar=no,
    location=0,
    status=no,
    menubar=no,
    scrollbars=yes,
    resizable=yes,
    width=500px,
    height=800px`
);

    var checkExternal;

    checkExternal = setInterval(function () {

            if (windowObjRef.closed) {

                clearInterval(checkExternal);

                localStorage.removeItem('saved');

            }

            else {

                var saved = localStorage.getItem('saved');

                if (saved === 'true') {

                    localStorage.setItem('saved', false);

                    saved = false;

                    // do some other stuff here

                }

            }

    }, 1000);   

}
```

this all works fine until i refresh the main page where the button is. Then the link of course seems to missing since the interval is not running with the reference `windowObjRef`. I don't want the `targetwindow` to be opened automatically on page load as well. It needs to be the button click. How can i detect in javascript if the `targetwindow` is actually open or closed?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264907/check-if-a-popup-window-is-closed answer your question?

Comment: no not really since i just want to know if the targetwindow is open or closed, if it's closed fine, no action. However if it's open then i need to call the interval loop again

Comment: did find a solution that works but not as i want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727036/closing-child-popup-window-when-parent-window-is-closed/24727281 in this case i just close the targetwindow and the user needs to open it again so the link is established. But i would prefer to just detect if the targetwindow is open or not