# How to make Google Chrome and iOS remember scroll position in div after returning back?

Tags: css, browser, scroll, position, back

The problem is that the scroll container is a `div`, not `body`. And that causes Google Chrome and iOS to fail to remember scroll position of the `div` after users go to another page and then return back.

The related CSS code is as follows. The scroll container is `#container`.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

html {
    height: 100%;
    }

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    }
```

And [here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w2wkcx0e/) on jsFiddle. Please reproduce the issue on Google Chrome and iOS by scrolling the content to about 50% (or any other noticeable length), click on a hyperlink to go to nother page, and then click browser's Back button.

Is there a uncomplicated way to make Google Chrome and iOS remember scroll position like Firefox does?

== EDIT in response to an answer ==

A simple .html file to test if any code in `onbeforeunload` works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            alert('Are you sure');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p><strong><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Go to Stack Overflow</a></strong>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas laoreet imperdiet diam, in sodales velit porta eget.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Demo Url and Session Based** https://jsfiddle.net/w2wkcx0e/6/

**Demo Url Based** https://jsfiddle.net/w2wkcx0e/3/

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/w2wkcx0e/1/

you could save the position at leaving page and reload it upon page reloading.

Let me know if doesn't work in all browsers you want it to work.

```
if (localStorage.scrollPos != undefined)
    $('#container').scrollTop(localStorage.scrollPos);

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    localStorage.setItem("scrollPos", $('#container').scrollTop());
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement `onbeforeunload` on my page but nothing happened. And then I searched and found [someone said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802007/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-in-chrome#answer-9411789) Chrome only allows using `onbeforeunload` to set message. Then I tested using `onbeforeunload` to set message on my page and that worked. However, your example on jsFiddle does work. That's weird. Any idea?

Comment: One work around would be sto save scrolltop position every half second and upon loading scroll to that position. This will do this but test performance.

Comment: I guess storing scrollTop value wouldn't be the best solution for my case. On my website, there are actually lots of pages which have `#container`. If users stored scrollTop value at page A and then go to page B, they would incorrectly jump to the position stored at page A.

Comment: Thank you. However, as stated above, codes in `onbeforeunload` somehow doesn't work if it is anything other than message.

Comment: but it's working, where does it not work, i checked ff and its working there too

Comment: I see. I will check it in detail tomorrow and let you know the result. Thank you.

Comment: @Muhannmad Umer, hi, I added a simple code at the bottom of the original post. You could save it as a .html file to test. The `alert('Are you sure')` within the `onbeforeunload` doesn't work in both Firefox and Google Chrome. But if you change `alert('Are you sure')` to `return 'Are you sure'`, then it works.

Comment: Perhaps storing scroll position is still not the best solution, even if it's url based. It could be confusing. For example, what if a visitor, via a direct link, revisited a page which he stored a scroll position previously? It's weird that a visitor jumps to a position when not visiting the page with Back button.

Comment: Maybe using `sessionStorage` inside `$('#container').scroll(function() { ...... })` could work. Not sure about performance issue though.

Comment: Thank you. Looking forward to your new version.

Comment: Actually i think session storage is a better option.